# Quickly find all Hostnames for a large list of IP addresses with python

Tags: python, dns, python-multiprocessing

I have a pandas data frame with an IP address column containing ~25k internal IP addresses. I am trying to find a much faster way to fill in missing hostnames in DNS name column. here is what I'm currently working with:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os, sys


def get_DNS_name(IP):
    import socket
    name = socket.gethostbyaddr(IP)
    return name[0]
data_p = 'IT-inventory.csv'
inv = pd.read_csv(data_p.replace('~$',''))
DNSnames = []
IPIloc = inv.columns.get_loc("IP Address")
dnsIloc = inv.columns.get_loc('DNS Name')
for index, row in inv.iterrows():
    IP= str(row[IPIloc])
    print(IP)
    DNSname = str(row[dnsIloc])
    if DNSname is not None:
        try:
            DNSname = get_DNS_name(IP)
        except:
            pass
    DNSnames.append(DNSname)  
inv['DNS Name'] = DNSnames
inv
```

The crux of this issue is that gethostbyaddr takes a few seconds per query, so I have considered trying to dump all of the records from the DNS server to the local machine and then merge but have been unsuccessful in finding a way to do that. I have also considered implementing multiprocessing to try to increase the number of parallel queries but don't know if that will even help.  Also concerned that I could accidentally DOS attack the DNS server by doing that.

Anyone know a better solution? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple DNS servers to query to for your requests. But 25k requests queried over say 10 DNS server in 1 minute is not a big enough number to consider it DOS attack.